# lemma: For a.e $\omega\in\Omega,\exists C(\omega)>0,\forall n\geq3,|Z_n(\omega)|\leq C(w)\sqrt{\ln(n)}$

Tags: analysis, solution-verification, proof-explanation, stochastic-analysis

For a.e $\omega\in\Omega,\exists C(\omega)>0,\forall n\geq3,|Z_n(\omega)|\leq C(w)\sqrt{\ln(n)}$

This is a lemma from my stochastic analysis course, and I have some basic calculation problems about the proof given by my lecturer.

let $\alpha>0,n\geq3$

$$
\mathbb{P}(|Z_n|\geq\sqrt{2\alpha \ln(n)})\\
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\mathbf{1}(y)_{\big|Z\geq\sqrt{2\alpha \ln(n)}\big|}exp(\frac{-y^2}{2})dy\\
\leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int^{\infty}_{\sqrt{2\alpha \ln(n)}} \frac{y}{\color{red}{\sqrt{2\alpha \ln(n)}}} exp(\frac{-y^2}{2})dy\\
=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha \ln(n)}}\Bigg[-exp(\frac{-y^2}{2})\Bigg]^{\infty}_{\sqrt{2\alpha \ln(n)}}\\
=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi\alpha \ln(n)}}\times exp(-\alpha \ln(n))\\=......
$$

**Q1** I don't understand why using an indicator function in calculating such probability, moreover, if just indicate the region of taking integral, **then why does on the inequality line there has an $y$ leftover as the numerator, isn't calculating probability just integral the pdf**? Besides, where is that red denominator comes from?

**Q2** If the inequality line is true, then it is not consistent with the third line, there should be an $\frac{1}{2}$?

Genuinely appreciate for any help and comment

---

Further thought about this:

1. does $y$ replaced by $z$ will more reasonable in  $$\mathbb{P}(|Z_n|\geq\sqrt{2\alpha ln(n)})\\
   =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\mathbf{1}(y)_{\big|Z\geq\sqrt{2\alpha ln(n)}\big|}exp(\frac{-y^2}{2})dy\\$$ and it turns to be $$\mathbb{P}(|Z_n|\geq\sqrt{2\alpha ln(n)})\\
   =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\mathbf{1}(z)_{\big|Z\geq\sqrt{2\alpha ln(n)}\big|}exp(\frac{-z^2}{2})dz\\$$
2. That inequality comes from the fact that $|Z\geq\sqrt{2\alpha ln(n)}|$ and some arrangement making $\frac{z}{\sqrt{2\alpha ln(n)}}>1$, and without absolute value so we are treating for two-tailed, so there is a two on numerator.

Comment: the y/sqrt(…) term comes as an approximation for “1”, due to the limits of integration it is actually typically greater than 1. the factor of 2 on the outside is to turn the two-sided integral of an even function into double a one-sided integral

Comment: @ChristianChapman Thank you for your reply. Is this so far correct?

Comment: yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @ChristianChapman Hi, I just re-edited my understanding, am I thinking correct?